# Convert point cloud to spline path

Tags: point-clouds, spline

Trying to convert a .csv file which is  a point cloud plot but in a sequential type plot..it has all three coordinates and a date time stamp/point..
What I’m trying to do is connect the dots and create a spline for other objects to attach…
Any help would be appreciated..
Was trying to follow the python script on another sub chat..
[Fit Curve-Spline to 3D Point Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64911820/fit-curve-spline-to-3d-point-cloud)

Was trying this in cinema4D but it doesn’t seemingly handle this level of work..this might be for python patch in blender…
But also mathlab or maple would be a good alternative if anyone out there can help, let me know…

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: Ever used [MeshLab](https://www.meshlab.net/)/[Source code](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab) + [CloudCompare](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/)/[source code](https://github.com/CloudCompare/CloudCompare). I hope the source code can help you out